# NullPointerException when setting adapter for ListView

Tags: java, android, sdk

I need help with my first swipe `Layout` and a `ListView`...
I would display some Text in the `ListView` but it doesn't work :(

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.evolutio.blocklaunch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

  private ListView mainListView ;  
  private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three

    // Find the ListView resource.   
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                      "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.news, planetList);  

    // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String>   
    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.   
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.  
    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

     public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

            int tabLayout = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            tabLayout = R.layout.news;
            break;
            case 1:
            tabLayout = R.layout.news;
            break;
            case 2:
            tabLayout = R.layout.news;
            break;
            }

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
}

}
```

---

XML-Files

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--
   This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
   titles for adjacent pages.
   -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
       android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:background="#33b5e5"
       android:paddingBottom="4dp"
       android:paddingTop="4dp"
       android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:padding="10dp"  
android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

**News.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:orientation="vertical"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
     android:id="@+id/mainListView">  
    </ListView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

And **the error**:

```
03-29 10:01:39.827: D/AndroidRuntime(6902): Shutting down VM
03-29 10:01:39.827: W/dalvikvm(6902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b521930)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.evolutio.blocklaunch/com.evolutio.blocklaunch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.evolutio.blocklaunch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-29 10:01:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     ... 11 more
03-29 10:01:42.327: I/Process(6902): Sending signal. PID: 6902 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305146/fragment-with-listview-nullpointerexception-on-setadapter

Comment: @oguzpamuk it's more than 2 years ago :) But thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong layout for `MainActivity` because you have added  `ListView` in `News.xml` but setting `activity_main` for `MainActivity` . you should use `News.xml` layout for MainActivity to initialize mainListView with `mainListView`   ListView in it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.News);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the next error and the App Force Close :) and sry for the very bad english :D

Comment: I have make a ListViewActivity.java with the Content of onCreate. Can I call the Activity when I swipe to the Tab News? http://pastebin.com/RuceXQYM

Comment: @Evolutio : use `setContentView(R.layout.News);`   instead of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`  in ListActivity becuase u have added ListView in News layout

Comment: @Evolutio: please don't re-use your question for any and all additional problems that you find in your program. If the answer solved the exception that you asked about in your original question you should accept the answer. If you find other problems that you want to ask about you should post an entirely new question.

Comment: what do you mean with "setContentView(R.layout.News);" instead of "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" I don't call the Activity ListActivity or?

Comment: @Evolutio : in which layout u have added ListView in xml?

Comment: news.xml why? I doesn't call any ListActivity, I create only the ListActivity.java :)

Comment: @Evolutio : ok have u tried it as `mainListView = getListView();`  ?

Comment: The method getListView() is undefined for the type MainActivity.

Don't work I follow this Tutorial: http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php#activity

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat says the problem is in line 74 of your MainActivity, but I think the real problem is in line 53:

`mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );`

I think mainListView is null because this layout element is not present in activity_main.xml (maybe it's loaded in line 82?)

You can try to move lines 53 and 74 after line 82...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.kt.listviewexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   /** Here two object are created mainListView and fruits of class ListView and String respectively 
    *   fruits is contains a set of data as array type
    */
    private ListView mainListView;
    String[] fruits = {
            "Mango",
            "Pine-Apple",
            "Guava",
            "Apple",
            "Banana",
            "Grapes",
            "Orange",
            "watermilon",
            "Dates",
            "Olive", 
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // called main UI
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Binding the object of ListView
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainlistview ); 

       /**
        * A fruitslist object is created of ArrayList type Which holds all element of array(Mango ,Pine-Apple...) , 
        *  in friutlist object
        */

       ArrayList<String> fruitlist = new ArrayList<String>();  
       fruitlist.addAll(Arrays.asList(fruits)); 

       /** Now all these data are bind with a ListView's object for appearance in android device or emulator
        *  with a parameter of current class , name of Xml file which contain TextView , id of that TextView
        *  and finally object of ArrayList in which we all those data
        */
        mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view, R.id.rowTextView, fruitlist));

        /** Call of listener when we click on every item of ListView
         * 
         */
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                if (position == 0) {
                      // do this on first item click
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                      // do this on second item click   
                } else {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " + fruits[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```